# How can I prefix all classes printed by a mixin in LESS?

Tags: less

I need to prefix with `bs-` all classes outputted by the mixing `.make-grid-columns`. Is this possible in LESS? The following isn't working:

```
.bs- {
  .make-grid-columns();
}
```

Output is:

```
.bs- .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, ...
```

But I need:

```
.bs-col-xs-1, .bs-col-sm-1, ...
```

Comment: What does `.make-grid-columns()` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the classed inside your mixin are prefixed with `&`

```
.make-grid-columns() {
  &.col-xs-1,
  &.col-sm-1,
  &.col-md-1,
  &.col-lg-1 {
    color: red;
  }
}

.bs- {
  .make-grid-columns();
}
```